# Get current date or time in Vim Command Line

Tags: vim

I found a few solutions to "insert" the current date and time, but how can I generate the formatted date/time in the command line? Here's what I wan to do:

```
cnoreabbrev newfile cd some/directory/ <bar> e file_name_[current_date] <CR>
```

So basically creating a new file with the current time attached to the name of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a start:

```
cnoreabbrev nnn e /tmp/foo_<c-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")<cr>
```

You can change the `nnn`, the path and the timestamp format.

Comment: Thanks Kent, but for some reason `<c-r>=` doesn't update the value. for `cnoreabbrev nnn <c-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")` I am getting `=strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")` and not the date.

Comment: So it seems `cnoreabbrev` doesn't evaluate the expression but other mappers like `nnoremap` does. Thank you.